# Performance of selective `receive` in Elixir/Erlang

Tags: erlang, elixir

When I have code like this:

```
receive do
  {:hello, msg} -> msg
end
```

And let's say I have `N` messages in my mailbox.  Is the performance of finding this particular message `O(1)`, `O(N)`, or something in between?

Comment: It's not O(1). Also, suppose you had N clauses in your receive? O(N-shite)?

Comment: Beside of all these discussion about the complexity/performance of selective receive (which is obviously a function of the number of pattern, their complexity, and in some cases the number of messages) don't forget that a good design should limit the number of clauses, facilitate the pattern matching (for example use a format {Tag,Rest}) and that the ideal size of the message queue is 0 (so garbage the unexpected messages).

Answer (score 6):

Receive perform a linear scan of the message box and then returns the first one which matches. There is one exception (Since [R14A](http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_R14A.readme))

> ```
> OTP-8623  == compiler erts hipe stdlib ==
>
>     Receive statements that can only read out a newly created
>     reference are now specially optimized so that it will execute
>     in constant time regardless of the number of messages in the
>     receive queue for the process. That optimization will benefit
>     calls to gen_server:call(). (See gen:do_call/4 for an example
>     of a receive statement that will be optimized.)
> ```

So in your case it is O(N) operation.

Answer (score 1):

The performance will grow linearly and in direct proportion to the number of elements in the mailbox, thus being O(N).

Comment: It is not how O() notation works. [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil, I have updated the answer not to step in unwanted land. I had referenced my previous answer on [Begginers guide to O notation](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation)

Answer (score 1):

Messaging in Erlang, hence Elixir, is "first in, first out". You browse them one by one and the first that's meet any clause in `receive` is handled. In worst case scenario you can choke up your messagebox.